# Radius of water droplets

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fluid-statics, liquid-state

What is the radius of water droplets  which are forming slowly then falling from ceiling, under the effect of gravitational force only, the other conditions are standard (293K temperature, 1 atm air pressure)

Comment: In your bathroom, switch on the hot shower and switch off the ventilation and wait. When it starts to rain take flash pictures in the dark. Set the focus to 50 cm with large diaphragm. Also take a picture of a measure from 50 cm. Switch off the shower and ventilate the bathroom. You should be able to estimate the droplet diameter by comparing the droplets in focus to the measure. Perform this on multiple droplets and specify the standard deviation. Hand in the report here by tomorrow.

Comment: I mean, can we calculate it theoretically?

Comment: Maybe this comes close: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(liquid)#Pendant_drop_test

Answer (score 1):

If we assume a hemispherical shape for the droplet before it gets detached from the ceiling, the surface tension force can be equated with gravity force.
$$\sigma \times \pi r=\rho g \times \frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$$
$$ r=\sqrt{\frac{3\sigma}{2\rho g}}$$
For the water air interface,  $\ \sigma=0.073 N/m$
$$\implies r=\sqrt{\frac{3\times 0.073}{2\times 1000\times 9.81}}=3.34mm$$
The obtained radius is for the hemispherical droplet. When it gets detached, it will approximately form a spherical shape (to have least interface area) which is having the same volume.
$$\implies \frac{2}{3}\pi \times 3.34^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi R_{drop}^3$$
$$R_{drop}=\frac{3.34}{\sqrt[3]{2}}=2.65mm$$

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed analysis you will find e.g. [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301839856_Modeling_Dropwise_Condensation_underneath_Unidirectional_Wettability_Graded_Surfaces). It takes the wettability of the surface into account.