# Surface area of liquid spilled over surface

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

How could one estimate the surface area occupied by a certain volume of liquid spilled over a surface?

I imagine it has to do with surface tension (therefore, ambient absolute pressure), however I imagine it is also different whether the droplets are discretized (many small droplets, minimum value) or gathered together (would the maximum value be that of a perfectly circular pool of continuous spill?).

Would surface curvature affect the result? Liquid density? Surface roughness? Ambient temperature would certainly affect air pressure, but is there any other effect caused by temperature differences (assume no heat transfer)?

Thanks in advance (question is not work or homework related: just spilled soda over my dinner and got me thinking).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651195/a-small-ring-of-droplets-that-are-formed-when-raindrop-falls